# Send mail to multiple users based on PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

This my table:

```
id      emails          names       vip     expire
1       1@exp.com       name1       1       2015/03/25 12:10:22
2       2@exp.com       name2       0   
3       3@exp.com       name3       1       2015/03/30 09:12:00
4       4@exp.com       name4       1       2015/05/01 20:10:11
5       5@exp.com       name5       1       2015/03/25 12:10:20
.
.
.
```

In this code:

Calls all users from the table where only users who have an active account.

If the account of users are expired then their account are deactivated and send e-mail to all users.

But e-mail will not be sent for all user that their account are 0 or not activate.

Active = 1 |
Not active = 0

The number of users is 2000 thousand and users are added every day.

I think that should be done to send email in a loop.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
if (!$db)
{
die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($db, $mysql_database) or die('Failed to select database<br>'.mysqli_error());

   $update = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE `vip` = '1' AND `expire` <= '".$update."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
        $emails = $data['emails'];
        $names = $data['names'];

        $sql = "UPDATE `".$mysql_table."` SET `vip` = '0' WHERE `vip` = '1' AND `expire` <= '".$update."'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);


        $msg = "Hi ".$names.",\nSecond line of text";
        mail($emails, "Expired Account", $msg);
   }
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: I hope this goes well for you, do you have any question?

Comment: @Naruto: Thanks for the answer, e-mail will not be sent for all user that their account not activate.

Comment: thats because your first queries only selects the users that are active?!

Comment: Using this code you get timeout. First fetch all your emails and store to a variable and after close connection start to send mail to them. Other solution is to increase timeout on php.ini or use set_time_limit. note: if you are using shared hosting make sure your host support this much mail per hour. I had same problem and i find out my host has 100 send mail limitation for each account.

Comment: @Naruto: Yes, exactly but my intention is that selects only users that are active, means users has VIP account and their account are active! I think it would be faster data retrieval.

Comment: @train_fox: I bought a hosting web and I will be able send 70 emails at one hour. May you get more help?

Comment: I think you can't handle this problem with this server. Let say you can make a perl code to check your jobs table for example and it does jobs that you added to jobs table. for sending 2000 email you must wait up to 29 hours. I think best solution is changing your host.

Answer (score 1):

After your select you need a while to send a email for each person.

instead:

```
 if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

try this:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: Oh. I had forgotten it, thanks a lot but in my hosting web I will be able send 70 emails at one hour and I have more than 2000 users What can I do for this?

Comment: @Mohammad change hoster.

Answer (score 1):

you maybe need a count:

```
$count=0
while ....


$count = $count+1;
if ($count <= 70){

  // your code to send emails
```

after this you need something to send after one hour maybe you configure cron in your server.